# How to split a string using STL?

Tags: c++, string, split

I try to split a string with multiple delimiters (spaces and parenthesis), but all I managed to do is a split with one delimiter thanks to `getline(...)`.

Here's an example of what I try to do:

```
hello world(12)
```

And I would like to get theses as strings:

```
hello
world
(
12
)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do matching. Use the below regex and then append the matched results to a list if necessary.

```
[^()\s]+(?=[()])|[^\s()]+|[()]
```

**Code:**

[Thanks to @Lightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561850/how-to-split-a-string-using-stl/28561981#comment45438598_28561981)

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s("hello world(12)");
    std::regex r("[^()\\s]+(?=[()])|[^\\s()]+|[()]");

    auto it  = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
    auto end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for ( ; it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << it->str() << '\n';
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/9)